# How to set solr.home in Glassfish with centOS?

Tags: glassfish, solr

I want use glassfish as the solr search server, but I don't know how to set the solr.home  in glassfish with centOS . I tried to set solr.home, but it didn't work. The error was: " looking for solr.xml: /var/deploy/solr/solr.xml "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try solr.solr.home instead ...

Comment: So... OP asks this question and marks this answer as accepted. Then asks essentially the same thing at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237535/how-to-set-solr-home-in-linux-os which means this solution didn't work?