# How to set solr/home in linux OS?

Tags: solr, tomcat6, catalina

I know how to configure `solr.home` by using Tomcat 6, but I don't know how to set `solr.home` by using Glassfish(V2.1). I have tried to set the `solr.home` in `.profile` as fellows:

```
export solr.home=/home/huenzhao/search/solr
export solr/home=/home/huenzhao/search/solr
export solr.solr.home=/home/huenzhao/search/solr
export JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/huenzhao/search/solr
```

and they all not work. The error is:

> HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log
>   files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want
>   solr to continue after configuration errors, change:
>   false in null
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in
>   classpath or 'solr/conf/',
>   cwd=/home/huenzhao/search/glassfish/domains/domain1/config at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:162)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:100) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:113) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:70) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:385)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:119)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4498)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5317)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:353) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:989)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:973)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:704)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1627)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1232)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:182)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:278)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeModuleDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:1005)
>   at

……

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 4):

if you are running solr inside tomcat as a container you can specify the solr home inside the XML descriptor for this webapp. (my terminology for this is probably a little off).

I've got xml fragments for each solr instance I want to run and they specify their own local solr home directory inside the xml fragment. The fragments live at /conf/Catalina/localhost and each one manages a solr instance. This way I can have multiple solr instances on the same machine each with their own solr home variable.

The info is here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

In paticular

> Create a Tomcat Context fragment to
>   point docBase to the
>   $SOLR_HOME/apache-solr-1.3.0.war file
>   and solr/home to $SOLR_HOME:
>
> Symlink
>   or place the file in
>   $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr-example.xml,
>   where Tomcat will automatically pick
>   it up. Tomcat deletes the file on
>   undeploy (which happens automatically
>   if the configuration is invalid).

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to deploy and configure Solr as a tomcat context.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/huenzhao/search/solr/"
```

Comment: I have tried, but it was also not work! 

The goal to set solr.home in tomcat6 is to start solr when the tomcat6 is starting. 

So I think the problem is that the solr can not start by set the solr.home when glassfish is starting.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a Java environment parameter from Java or edit your VM configuration:

```
System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", "/home/user/apache-solr-1.4/example/solr");
```

In my case I simply copied the 'solr' folder to glassfish/domains/domain1/config and it worked.